# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{$$typeof, render}).If you meant to render a collection of children,use anarrayinstead

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

This error occurring after I add the `Alerts.js` component. If I remove the component `Alert.js`, it works normally, and add this component in `App.js` this error occurs.

```js
//Alert.js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";
export class Alerts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.alert.show("Its, Worked");
  }
  render() {
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}
export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

```js
// App.js file here I want to import Alerts.js

........// More Imports
import { positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "react-alert-template-basic";
import Alerts from "./layout/Alerts";
....... // More Code
//ALert Options
const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: positions.TOP_CENTER,
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
          <Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Alerts />
            <div className="container">
              <Dashboard />
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </AlertProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert), you should be calling `withAlert` like this:

```
export default withAlert()(Alerts);
```